# What is the best way to configure a VPS Server, with ISPConfig or EasyEngine?

Tags: linux, webserver, vps, configuration-managment

in order to install WordPress on a VPS server, according to your experience what is the difference between using an ISPConfig type panel or using EasyEngine in the configuration and management of the server? Which would be the best option?

Answer (score 0):

As EasyEngine simply sets up the environment so the Admins dont have to waste time through a manual process, and the source is available as a GIT, you can go through the scripts and modify them and change the target locations.

ISPConfig creates a client group on the system per user you add, and a web user per site, locking things down to that level.

The directory structure would be /var/www/clients/client4/web17/web. You will need to start by adding in those two extra args to the EE script, client4, web17 for example, then change the location that it downloads WordPress to that location.

As ISPConfig saves and creates the nginx config from the database, you could hook into that and add the config into the extras portion, the same way EE recommends it.

Lastly, you need to ensure that the NGINX you install has the same components that EE uses. So very doable, but your making a custom solution for your setup, and would need to track any changes EE does to its master version so as to stay in sync.

It would probably be easier to change EE to accept args to have a similar setup with client/web so you can hook the quota system into, a small DB that keeps and tracks these values, and CLI when you change them.